Linphone maven repo is not searched for when looking for linphone-sd-android
I am building a fork of linphone and am trying to rename the package to my own app name
Before it built without problems.
AfterI ran a search-replace for org.linphone in the entire project (except for the
implementation 'org.linphone:linphone-sdk-android:5.3+'

in app/build.gradle)and  renamed the linphone directory  it errors with

   > Could not find any matches for org.linphone.minimal:linphone-sdk-android:5.3+ as no versions of org.linphone.minimal:linphone-sdk-android are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/linphone/minimal/linphone-sdk-android/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/linphone/minimal/linphone-sdk-android/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://www.jitpack.io/org/linphone/minimal/linphone-sdk-android/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/linphone/minimal/linphone-sdk-android/maven-metadata.xml

I did already added the

    maven {
        url "https://linphone.org/maven_repository/"
    }

to the repositories block in the top level build.gradle and replaced
    implementation 'org.linphone:linphone-sdk-android:5.3+'

with
debugImplementation "org.linphone:linphone-sdk-android-debug:5.3+"
releaseImplementation "org.linphone:linphone-sdk-android:5.3+"

in app/build.gradle as suggested in https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/Android/. Note however how the linphone repo is not listed among the locations searched for.
I've ran
./gradlew clean
./gradlew --refresh-dependencies

and then ran the build but it still gives me the same error.
Adding
        implementation files('linphone-sdk.jar')

gives me the error
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.


Seems like they changed repository URL.
Early I had
maven {url "https://linphone.org/maven_repository/"}

in build.gradle project-level file and faced the same issue.
Now I have replaced it with
maven {url "https://download.linphone.org/maven_repository/"}

Found this in their commit on github: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/commit/c4eb74ff0dc25a9476eb71113059b2f7599183eb
Now project builds fine.

According to https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-android#create-an-apk-with-a-different-package-name, you don't need to do a search/replace of org.linphone package name to replace it by yours, simply to set the one you want in the build.gradle file in the packageName variable.

Same here. I cant even compile the latest android version 5.2:
https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/tree/release/5.2#js-repo-pjax-container
But, using the arr file, works.
//    implementation 'org.linphone:linphone-sdk-android:5.3+'
implementation files('linphone-sdk-android-5.3.95.aar')

